# Trouble with externalizing Spring Boot resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am attempting to externalize some properties and resources; specifically, a properties file and a json file

I have a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("sheets.properties")
public class SheetsConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="sheets.secrets")
    public GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets(GoogleClientSecretsFactory clientSecretsFactory, 
                                             @Value("${sheets.credentials.file}") String credentialFileName) {
        return clientSecretsFactory.buildWithResourceCredentials(credentialFileName);

        // which calls GoogleClientSecretsFactory.class.getResourceAsStream(credentialsFilePath);
        // ${sheets.credentials.file} should resolve to "/sheets.json"
    }

    //...
}
```

My launch directory looks like this:

```
root@foobar:~/# ls ~ -al
total 34292
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Mar  8 19:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Mar  7 19:39 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35086447 Mar  8 20:50 foo.jar
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Mar  8 19:23 logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      436 Mar  8 20:51 sheets.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       91 Mar  8 20:51 sheets.properties
```

Per the documentation on externalizing configuration, I figured it should be
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

`root@foobar:~/# java -jar ~/foo.jar --spring.config.location=file:~/sheets.properties`

or

`root@foobar:~/# java -jar ~/foo.jar --spring.config.additional-location=file:~/sheets.properties`

or

`root@foobar:~/# java -jar ~/foo.jar --spring-config-name=application,sheets --spring.config.location=file:~/`

But every time:

```
2021-03-08 20:51:13,598 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [foo.Main]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [sheets.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [sheets.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

---

Everything works fine if the resources are packaged with the jar, but credential information should obviously be externalized.

What am I overlooking in including external properties and resources for spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the absolute path  of your properties file in your class like this:

```
@PropertySource("file:${FOO_PATH}sheets.properties")
```

Then set its value while starting your app:

`java -jar -DFOO_PATH=/your/project/path/ ~/foo.jar`

Use `\\` as path separators on windows.

Comment: So, this was *almost* exactly what I needed! I needed 

`@PropertySource("file:sheets.properties")`

which was fine with the sheets being adajacent. without the 'file' being specified tho, Spring was defaulting to only looking in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

**`root@foobar:~/#`** `java -jar ~/foo.jar --spring.config.name=sheets.properties`

By default **Spring Boot** will override your configuration files based on the location they are placed. By default however it will try to load as property file a file with name `application.properties` or `application.yml`. Because you have a custom properties file you have to declare it.

As for file location. Outer configuration files override the inner files. So if you have in your resources inside jar a `sheets.properties` the outer file in your current directory will override it. You don't need  any special property for that.

Hence if you execute your Jar with the above command your properties file from your current directory will be loaded.

Check the following link to understand how to apply externalized configuration and also from which directories spring boot tries to load properties by default.

[Spring boot externalized properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

Comment: Just tried. Same result.

Also, the documentation you linked to is for Spring-Boot 1.0.1; is there something in particular that I should be seeing to explain this behavior, which isn't in the 2.1.9 documentation that I linked in my question?

Comment: can you try placing an empty `sheets.properties` in your project resources? And check if the overrided one from current directory is also loaded. Maybe it just needs one in the classpath and then when found goed forward as this being the basic and also gets overriden by others higher in hierarchy